# tz.inDaylightTime(new Date()) returning true for timezone GMT+8 for ID:- Asia/Choibalsan which is wrong

Tags: java, date, timezone

***Problem with TimeZone:***-Beijing,Chongqing,Hong Kong,Urumqi (GMT 8)

***In Debug Getting Ids for above time zone
 :-***[Antarctica/Casey, Asia/Brunei, Asia/Chita, Asia/Choibalsan, 
Asia/Chongqing, Asia/Chungking, Asia/Harbin, Asia/Hong_Kong, 
Asia/Irkutsk, Asia/Kuala_Lumpur, Asia/Kuching, Asia/Macao, 
Asia/Macau, Asia/Makassar, Asia/Manila, Asia/Shanghai, 
Asia/Singapore, Asia/Taipei, Asia/Ujung_Pandang, Asia/Ulaanbaatar, 
Asia/Ulan_Bator, Australia/Perth, Australia/West, CTT, Etc/GMT-8, Hongkong, PRC, Singapore]

***Problem:-tz.inDaylightTime(new Date()) returning true for id Asia/Choibalsan***
 and giving 3600000 daylight difference. because of this its showing time 1 hour ahead to hongkong user.because it is adding 3600000 as day light saving difference

**Which is wrong because daylight saving in no for Hong-kong time zone.  "tz.inDaylightTime()" should return false here.**

This isssue is coming on production on linux server, JDK8.

it is working on local system on windows with JDK8.

**My code for reference:-**

```
public static String setDateTimeInTimezone(Date date, String userTimeZone) {
    int offset = parseTimeZone(userTimeZone);
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

    int timezoneDSTSaving = 0;
    String[] timeArray = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs(offset);
    TimeZone tz=null;
    for (int i = 0; i < timeArray.length; i++) {
        tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeArray[i]);
        if (tz.inDaylightTime(new Date())) {
            timezoneDSTSaving = tz.getDSTSavings();
        }
        if (timezoneDSTSaving != 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
    //formatter.setTimeZone(tz);
    return formatter.format(new Date(date.getTime() + offset + timezoneDSTSaving));
}

public static int parseTimeZone(String userTimeZone) {
    // Represent GMT String used to display user time zone.
    final String gmtStringConstant = GMT_OFFSET_STRING;
    // Represent 60 minute in a hour.
    final int minutes = 60;
    // Represent 60 seconds in minute.
    final int seconds = 60;
    // Represent 1000 milli seconds in second.
    final int milliseconds = 1000;
    int timezoneDifference = 0;
    int gmtIndex = userTimeZone.indexOf(gmtStringConstant);
    // If "(GMT" String is not found in timezone, return 0.
    if (gmtIndex == -1) {
        return timezoneDifference;
    }
    String timeZone = userTimeZone.substring(gmtIndex + gmtStringConstant.length(), userTimeZone.length() - 1);
    int indexOfColon = timeZone.indexOf(":");
    if (indexOfColon != -1) {
        int hourDiff = Integer.parseInt(timeZone.substring(0, indexOfColon)) * minutes * seconds * milliseconds;
        int minDiff = Integer.parseInt(timeZone.substring(indexOfColon + 1)) * seconds * milliseconds;
        if (hourDiff < 0) {
            minDiff *= -1;
        }
        timezoneDifference = hourDiff + minDiff;
    } else {
        timezoneDifference = Integer.parseInt(timeZone) * minutes * seconds * milliseconds;
    }
    return timezoneDifference;
}
```

**Note : i dont want to use ZODATIME i want to handle with util date only**

Comment: Why aren't you simply using `formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(userTimeZone))`? If the user has specified the time zone, you shouldn't need to search at all.

Comment: what version of JDK 8 are you running in both environments?

Comment: I have "String userTimeZone="Beijing,Chongqing,Hong Kong,Urumqi (GMT 8)"   as timezone not ID like "Asia/Choibalsan". and getTimeZone(userTimeZone) is expecting ID like Asia/Choibalsan for example. Please help hhow i can handle this??

Comment: JDK version 1.8.0_40 is being used. how this version matters for this??

Comment: when i am doing formatter.setTimeZone(tz); and in debug mode adding some value to tz dstSaving then that values are not getting added to formated date

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

- DST was in effect in `Asia/Choibalsan` up until 2016-09-23 when observance was halted. Now the year-round offset is +08:00.
- You are using terrible date-time classes that should now be avoided.

## *java.time*

> Note : i dont want to use ZODATIME i want to handle with util date only

The terrible `java.util.Date` class was supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes as of the adoption of [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Specify your desired time zone as a [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html) object.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Choibalsan" ) ;
```

Get the rules for that zone, the history of past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of that region. Get a [`ZoneRules`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/zone/ZoneRules.html) object.

```
ZoneRules rules = z.getRules() ;
```

Specify a moment for which we want to determine if DST was in effect or not. You asked this Question at Apr 6 '16 at 12:32, so let's use that moment.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2016 , Month.APRIL , 6 ) ;
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of( 12 , 32 ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( ld , lt , z ) ;
```

> zdt.toString():

Adjust into UTC by extracting a [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html).

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;  // Extract a `Instant`, adjusting from time zone to UTC.
```

Ask [if DST was in effect](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/zone/ZoneRules.html#isDaylightSavings(java.time.Instant)) at that moment in that zone.

```
boolean inDst = rules.isDaylightSavings​( instant ) ;
```

And ask what was the amount of that DST adjustment (if DST in effect).

```
Duration d = rules.getDaylightSavings​( instant ) ;
```

See [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/og4BDM).

> zdt.toString(): 2016-04-06T12:32+09:00[Asia/Choibalsan]
>
> instant.toString(): 2016-04-06T03:32:00Z
>
> inDst.toString(): true

We get a result saying that at moment `Asia/Choibalsan` was indeed in DST.

Let's try the current moment.

```
System.out.println(
    ZoneId
    .of( "Asia/Choibalsan" )
    .getRules()
    .isDaylightSavings( 
        Instant.now() 
    )
);
```

We get `false`, *not* currently in DST. This agrees with [the report by Time.is](https://time.is/Choibalsan) web site, not currently in DST, while also claiming that `+08:00` is the year-round offset for `Asia/Choibalsan`.

## DST dropped by `Asia/Choibalsan` after 2016-09-23

These results are consistent with the [report by this site](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/mongolia/choibalsan) that observance of DST was dropped in that time zone, with the last DST transition on September 23, 2016.